# Can Obito's ocular jutsu acces multiple dimensions?

Tags: naruto

In the Naruto anime, Obito saved sasuke from Oonoki's particle dismantling jutsu and then sent Sasuke into his dimension. He also sent Karin into the dimension so she could heal Sasuke.

Obito then went after Danzo Shimura but then he had to fight Danzo's subbordinates first (they were buying enough time for Danzou to unseal his arm).  During the fight between Obito and Danzous subordinates(Toruno Aburame and Fu Yamanaka). Obito sucked the 2 of them into his dimension. However, sasuke and Karin were already in the dimension at that time.

This part really confused me cause Obito went back into his dimension but then the only people inside were Sasuke and Karin. I always thought Obito's Kamui was connected to just 1 dimension but then the fact that the 2 of Danzous subordinates were nowhere to be seen doesnt add up.

Does this mean Obito could use Kamui to multiple dimensions? If not then why were the 2 of Danzo's subordinates not in the same dimension as sasuke and Karin, we didnt even see them when Obito went back into the dimension to speak to Sasuke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As far as I know,Obito has only 1 dimension.Both Danzou's subordinates and Sasuke,Karin were in the same dimension.

You are forgetting that Obito has a dimension under his control.An entire dimension.Not a room.A dimension.That's another parallel universe.Read more about dimensions here:  https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/some-speculative-theoretical-ideas-for-the-lhc/extra-dimensions/how-to-look-for-signs-of-extra-dimensions/how-big-could-an-extra-dimension-be/

Danzou's subordinates could be anywhere in Obito's dimension,maybe millions of miles away,so they would never make it to Sasuke and Karin.

Comment: It was also shown that when Kabuto was explaining how the Edo Tensei jutsu works to Tobi, that Danzo's subordinates were under genjutsu they couldn't resist. He probably kept them under it so they didn't cause any harm in his Time-Space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he saved Sasuke from being trapped in one of kaguyas dimension by opening a portal to such dimension

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.